# Showing this series converges uniformly on $[-1,0]$ but not on $[-1,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

**Question 1:** I want to show that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n}$ converges uniformly on $[-1,0]$, so I am trying to show equivalently that $$\sup\limits_{x\in[-1,0]}\left|\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n} - \sum\limits_{n=1}^m \dfrac{x^n}{n}\right|=\sup\limits_{x\in[-1,0]}\left|\sum\limits_{n=m+1}^\infty \dfrac{x^n}{n}\right|\rightarrow 0$$ as $m\rightarrow\infty$. I'm having some difficulties, perhaps there's a clever trick I'm missing. I think the supremum is when $x=-1$ after computing the sum for a couple values in $[-1,0]$ and seeing that the sums get closer to $0$ as $x\rightarrow 0$.

**Question 2** I know that the series fails to converge uniformly on $[-1,1)$. This is unsurprising, as the supremum is no longer at $x=-1$ (I think the supremum does not exist, after calculating several values close to $1$). How can I make this more precise?

Comment: By properties of alternating series,  if $-1\le x\lt 0$ the "tail" has absolute value less than $\frac{1}{m+1}$.  For question 2, we can say it is because of divergence at $1$.

Comment: The series converges to $-\log(1-x)$ for $-1\le x<1$.  Note that the supremum of the limit function is unbounded at $1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Can you tell me how to get $\left|\sum\limits_{n=m+1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}\right|<\frac{1}{m+1}$ from the properties of the alternating series? I know that the absolute value of the sum is largest when $x=-1$ but I am confused about your conclusion.

Comment: Let $1\le x\lt 0$. Let $m+1$ be even (we can do odd in the same way. Then the tail has shape $(a_{m+1}-a_{m+2})+(a_{m+3}-a_{m+4})+\cdots$, so is positve.  But the tail is also $a_{m+1}-(a_{m+2}-a_{m+3})-(a_{m+4}-a_{m+-5})-\cdots$ so is less than $a_{m+1}$.  So the tail is between $0$ and $a_{m+1}$.   I find typing in comments difficult, so if this is not enough I will have to write an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible sketch of question $2$ might look like:

> Suppose $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$$ converges uniformly on $[-1,1)$. Then there exists $K \in \Bbb{R}_{>0}$ such that $$\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n} \right| \leq K$$ for all $x \in [-1,1)$.

From here you can use the fact that your series approaches the harmonic series as $x \to 1$, which is well known to diverge to $+\infty$. This will serve to establish that for all $K \in \Bbb{R}_{>0}$ you can find $x \in [-1,1)$ such that $\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n} \right| > K$.

Comment: How does showing that the series is bounded by $K$ imply uniform convergence (or "non-uniform" convergence)?  The series converges to $-\log(1-x)$ for $-1\le x<1$.  So, we already know that $\lim_{x\to 1}\log(1-x)$ diverges.  Isn't that adequate, since the supremum of the limit function is unbouned?

Comment: @Dr.MV I like that, it is easier than my answer. I wasn't sure if the user who asked the question was allowed to assume the series converges to $-\log(1-x)$ on $[-1,1)$. As I say in my first sentence my answer is just a possible sketch of how a proof might look.

Comment: I would like to use an argument in the flavor of the answer that @graydad gave. What value of $x$ should I choose?

Comment: @user1227849937 can you use the the fact that the series converges to $-\ln(1-x)?$ If so it will be very easy to solve for $x$.